# Inconvertible types in Generics

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren’t Java’s generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

I need help understanding whats going on.

I have an interface

```
public interface Foo {

  Map<String, ParameterValue> getParameters();
}

public interface ParameterValue { }
```

And an implementation of Foo.

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {
   Map<String, ParameterValueImpl> parameters = new HashMap<String, ParameterValueImpl>();
   //ParameterValueImpl an implementation of ParameterValue

@Override
    public Map<String, ParameterValue> getParameters() {
        return ((Map<String,ParameterValue>) parameters);
    }   

}
```

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
failure [ERROR]
src/main/java/domainJPA/model/FooImpl.java:[92,45]
inconvertible types [ERROR] found   :
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,domainJPA.model.ParameterValueImpl>
[ERROR] required:
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,domain.model.ParameterValue>
```

I have to use the ParameterValue in the interface of Foo, and in FooImpl I must just the implementation of ParameterValue (ParameterValueImpl) because its an @Entity and jpa requires it.

How can I make this code compile?

**EDIT**

If I change the code to `? extends ParameterValue` as suggested in one of the answers, then I cannot use the Foo interface.

The following code results in compilation error: `The method put(String, capture#8-of ? extends ParameterValue) in the type Map<String,capture#8-of ? extends ParameterValue> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ParameterValueImpl)`

`foo.getParameters().put("test", new ParameterValueImpl);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about it -- if the return value from `getParameters()` is actually a `Map<String, ParameterValueImpl>`, then you have the ability to add a value to the map that derives from `ParameterValue`, but not `ParameterValueImpl`.  You would be breaking type safety by doing that.

You have two options to correct this:

1. In `getParameters()`, copy the map into a new map of the correct type.
2. Use `Map<String, ParameterValue>` as the type for `FooImpl.parameters`.

Comment: I can't do the second part as The FooImpl is an JPA entity, and If I use the interface, it will not recognize it. I didn't quite understand the 1 one.

Comment: You may wind up having to make `Foo` a generic interface then, where the type parameter is used as the second type parameter to the map.

Comment: I understood the copy part, and I went for that instead. Seems to work for now.

Comment: Beware though, since you are returning a copy, adding items to the map returned by this method will have *no effect* on the map contained in the `FooImpl` instance.  Consider returning an read-only copy so that any attempt to modify the map will result in an error.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your interface method to: -

```
Map<String, ? extends ParameterValue> getParameters();
```

Now, you can return a Map of `String` and any type implementing your `ParameterValue`

Then you dont' need a typecast in your implementation of this method.

```
public Map<String, ? extends ParameterValue> getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}
```

---

Or, since you can store a `ParameterValueImpl` type instance in a `ParameterType` reference, so, you can also change the `Map` in your `FooImpl` class as: -

```
Map<String, ParameterValue> parameters = new HashMap<String, ParameterValue>();
```

then your original method will work.

Comment: If I use the `? extends ParameterValue` then the following code doesn`t compile: foo.getParameters().put("test", new ParameterValueImpl());` it gives me the error message `The method put(String, capture#8-of ? extends ParameterValue) in the type Map<String,capture#8-of ? extends ParameterValue> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ParameterValueImpl)`

Comment: Well, you can't modify the Map if it is a type of `? extends Type`. Because you don't know what type you may actually insert. If you want to modify your Map. Then you should probably go with the 2nd way.